# Sagemaker lifecycle config: could not find conda environment conda_python3 | works fine in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, anaconda, conda, amazon-sagemaker

I have prototyped some code using conda_python3 environment in SageMaker notebook instance. When I open terminal, activate environment and run code it works well but when I try to automate the process by using lifecycle configuration, system is unable to identify the environment. I get the following message on cloud watch

```
2020-07-16T11:25:37.576+05:30
Could not find conda environment: conda_python3

2020-07-16T11:25:37.576+05:30
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

My life cycle config code:

```
#!bin/bash

set -e

ENVIRONMENT=conda_python3

source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate "$ENVIRONMENT"

python /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/scrub_testing.py

source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try doing this

```
#!/bin/bash


set -e


ENVIRONMENT=conda_python3
NOTEBOOK_FILE=/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/scrub_testing.ipynb


source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate "$ENVIRONMENT"


nohup jupyter nbconvert "$NOTEBOOK_FILE" --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python3  --execute scrub_testing.ipynb


source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
```